# Pear mail using php script just stops

Tags: php, email, pear

I have been trying to send mail using pear and php script.  I have searched for over a day now, and have yet to find out my issue.  When I run this code in a website, nothing happens.  It quickly loads and then stops.  I ran some echo commands, and I found that the code specifically stops at:

```
$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
```

And that is it.  Nothing else happens.  I don't get any error input or anything, I just see my echo occur right before this and no echo after it.  I have pear installed, as well as pear mail.  I 'think' i installed them correctly, because i can type "pear" into command line anywhere and it brings up the menu.  I have opened port 465, tcp, through my router and my firewall.  I am on a windows xp machine.  I don't know where the error log would be to see if anything undesirable is happening.  My server is apache 2.2, hosted on this windows box.

```
 <?php

 require_once "Mail.php";

 $from = "user1@gmail.com";
 $to = "user2@yahoo.com";
 $subject = "Hi!";
 $body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";

 $server = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
 $username = "user1@gmail.com";
 $password = "pass";

 $headers = array (
   "From" => $from,
   "To" => $to,
   "Subject" => $subject);
 $smtp = Mail::factory("smtp",
   array ("host" => $server,
         "port" => 465,
         "auth" => true,
         "username" => $username,
         "password" => $password));
 $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
 if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
   echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
  } else {
   echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
  }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Gota love how these problems can take 10 hours of work and be so simple.

So when I configured PEAR, I did it correctly.  I installed the packages mail, mail_mime, and net_socket.  I *tried* to install net_smtp, but it was giving me the random error "no releases available for package pear...".  I assumed that it meant the package was installed and I couldn't do anything else with it. I don't know exactly how this thing got bugged, but essentially a pear folder was generated in my "C:\Documents and Settings\user\Local Settings\Temp" folder.  I deleted this folder named pear, and then ran 'pear install net_smtp' successfully.  After that, I ran my php code and everything worked like a charm (was able to send my email successfully through the gmail smtp server).

Thanks for the help and I am so relieved to have figured this out! :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to port forward because the connection is outbound. Possibly your ISP is blocking the connection. Common on outbound port 25, not so much on 465 but it happens.
Anyway, your code looks fine.

Comment: I was thinking about things, and would the [mail function] in my php.ini file impact this? I had it set to go through att outbound smtp server initially because i was trying to do mail through my isp. By the way, does anyone know if att blocks port 465?  My mail function.  [mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = ssl://smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port = 465

; For Win32 only.
sendmail_from = user1@gmail.com

Comment: I don't think php.ini would have anything to do with this, no. What happens when you open up a command prompt run "telnet smtp.gmail.com 465"? does it go blank and give you a blinking cursor or do you get "connecting to ..." forever?

Comment: It goes blank and gives me a cursor.

Comment: In that case you are connecting and the problem is not your ISP or your router / computer. It's probably a problem specifically with Pear. Is there a reason you can't use PHP's [built-in mail() function](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php), if only for troubleshooting?

Comment: My understanding is that the PHP built in mail() function does not have support for ssl/smtp on its own.  I need to have some other addon (like pear), so I can use the gmail server.